# React-Native Tooltip Issue

Tags: react-native, tooltip, react-native-elements

I'm trying to find a simple working tooltip for react-native but I can't find any. All of them has many many bugs. I'd like to describe an issue in "react-native-elements/Tooltip" (version 3.4.2) and also ask for a working tooltip component.

```
...
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.pageTitle}>{this.props.messages.account}</Text>
                <View style={styles.horizontalFlex}>
                    <Text
                        style={styles.userInfo}>{this.props.messages.subscriptionModel}: {this.props.route.params.userProfile}
                    </Text>
                    <Tooltip popover={<Text>Info here</Text>}>
                        <EntypoIcon style={styles.infoIcon} name="info-with-circle" size={20} color={Colors.DARK_BLUE}/>
                    </Tooltip>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
...

let styles = EStyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "column",
    },
    pageTitle: {
        ...
    },
    userInfo: {
        textAlign: "left",
        justifyContent: "center",
        marginLeft: "20rem",
        color: Colors.DARK_BLUE,
        fontSize: "15rem",
        marginBottom: "10rem"
    },
    infoIcon: {
        paddingLeft: "20rem",
    },
    horizontalFlex: {
        flexDirection: "row"
    }
});
...
```

The output for the above code is the following:

[image]

Somehow the icon which I'm putting a Tooltip to, slides above. It doesn't matter if it's an icon or a text, same issue occurs. How do I fix this? Do you know any other working tooltip in react-native which you tried and saw that it is working recently?

Comment: I am using that one with same version , never experienced that issue . might be on your layout or other views ?

Comment: @heathkev That's all I have above, no other layout or view in this component. Could you try the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to set withOverlay to false and skipAndroidStatusBar to true. This wasn't what I needed but still it's acceptable. Here is the code:

```
<Tooltip 
    popover={<Text style={...text style here...}>Change here</Text>}
    withOverlay={false}
    skipAndroidStatusBar={true}
    containerStyle={...container style here...}
    backgroundColor={...color...}>
```

Answer (score 0):

With native-base, tooltip can be used in Android. Here is the example code:

```html
import React from "react";
import { Tooltip, Button, Center, NativeBaseProvider } from "native-base";

function Example() {

    const [tipShown, setTipShown] = React.useState(false);

    const buttonLongPressed = () => {
        setTipShown(!tipShown)
    }


    return <Center>
        <Tooltip label="Click here to read more" openDelay={500}
            isOpen={tipShown}>
            <Button onLongPress={buttonLongPressed}>More</Button>
        </Tooltip>
    </Center>;
}

export default () => {
    return (
        <NativeBaseProvider>
            <Center flex={1} px="3">
                <Example />
            </Center>
        </NativeBaseProvider>
    );
};
```